# Android what engine could i use for a game like this?

Tags: java, android

What engine could i use to make a game like?
http://www.keepbusy.net/play.php?id=zombie-trailer-park

Comment: It looks simple enough to code from scratch, really.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking! I was just making sure haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with code, I recommend coding such a game from scratch. The mechanics seem very simple and there's no functionality that an engine would provide that you can't code yourself. It will be more flexible, and you'll learn more by solving some of the problems directly. Just make sure you have a clean design and keep it manageable.

You seem to want some pointers on how to get started, so I'll suggest a basic framework for your game. Create a class that encapsulates a game object. It should have coordinates, width, height, etc; any field or method that is common to all objects in your game. Use derived classes to implement all the specific behaviours. Make sure you understand OOP and how it is implemented in Java.

You'll need to store the game objects in lists or arrays. Depending on your implementation, it may make sense to have one list/array for all objects, or perhaps two lists/arrays, one friendly, one enemy, or some other setup. You'll need to decide which makes most sense. To answer your specific question about distances, in the example you can just take the absolute difference between the x coordinates a zombie and an opposing zombie and see if it's within the attack range.

Comment: Thank you Zong! If you don't mind me asking. I don't know how to PM on this website. Can I have your skype or Gtalk just so I can ask you some questions. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to provide such information on an open forum. What kind of questions do you have in mind? You may be able to get answers on this site...

Comment: How can I make two characters attack each others once they are in contact?

Comment: Mhm, How do i do the range part?

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

From Here you can get 8 Open Source Game Engine for android.

http://ntt.cc/2011/05/08/8-open-source-android-game-engines.html

You can choose anyone who fulfilled your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/blog/). It is used for 2D games and have been around for a while. I personally used it before writing my own. It is open source and has some great examples that you can learn on.

Comment: AndEngine is giving me abunch of @Override errors how can i fix this

Comment: Have a look at the [link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/) if it is engine specific errors. But sometimes if the project is built with Java 5 instead of Java 6, it can get java related @Override errors.